# Docker on windows throwing hash sum mismatch

Tags: windows, docker

I am trying to build the project on Windows and I am using Docker for Windows but when I run the command `docker-compose build` I get the following error:

```
libltdl-dev_2.4.6-0.1_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch  E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y
```

I tried several different solutions like reinstalling the Docker, using older Docker versions, I tried modifying the Dockerfile in the project, I tried switching to different branches of the project. As far as I know, this is a Windows issue, this does not apply to other operating systems. 
Any suggestion what should I do next?